# Genymotion prevents Droid 4X from running

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I've installed Droid 4X simulator a few months ago and found it to be a great simulator/emulator for both running Android games and debugging apps.

Just today, I installed Genymotion (with virtual box) because I needed to test multiple devices across different Android OS versions.

Once completed, Genymotion works fine, however, Droid 4X will no longer load. It gets stuck @ 99% and says it needs to be repaired using [Tweaking.com 's Windows Repair](http://www.droid4x.cn/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3987&extra=page%3D1).

I'm positive that the installation of Genymotion/Virtual Box has somehow interfered with my Droid 4X, but I have no clue how to identify the problem and fix it. Currently, what I do notice is that when I close my Droid 4X (and even quit the process via task manager), the Virtual Box still shows Droid 4X as running.

How can I fix this issue and run my Droid 4X again?

Comment: May be you try to assign different host only network adapters to genymotion and droid4x? I'll try it right now.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall virtuul box then restart and try opening droid 4x again

Comment: Shouldn't be a answer but a comment